# How can I add failover in custom load balancer?

Tags: apache-camel

HTTP response code in range 100 to 299 is considered as success response in Camel. My requirement is that if response code is anything other than 200 then consider that as failure response. I'm trying to achieve this using custom load balancer. Problem is that when exchange is processed and if response code is 299 then for Camel it is success and it goes out of customLoadBalancer. I need a way to add custom failover in which I can check response header value and based on that route to different endpoints.

```
<route id="client_http" errorHandlerRef="noErrorHandler">
        <from uri="direct:test"/>
        <loadBalance inheritErrorHandler="false">
        <custom ref="customLoadBalancer" />
            <!-- TODO configurable failover attempts -->
            <to ref="http4.1.to"/>
            <to ref="http4.2.to"/>
            <to ref="http4.3.to"/>
        </loadBalance>
    </route>

@Component
public class CustomLoadBalancer extends LoadBalancerSupport {

  public boolean process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback callback) {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CustomLoadBalancer.class);
    String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    log.debug("Headers " + exchange.getIn().getHeaders()); //null because exchange is not processed
    getProcessors().get(0).process(exchange);
    log.debug("Headers " + exchange.getIn().getHeaders()); //line never executes because HTTP response was 299 and Camel considered that as success.
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you cannot use the built-in failover load balancer?

Comment: Built-in failover works only if response code is higher than 299.

Comment: Then use a custom http binding on the http component to make those values as failures too

Comment: I logged a ticket to allow to configure this range on the http components: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9078

Comment: Thank you Claus. As this has been fixed in 2.16.0, looks like only option I have is to use custom http binding. I tried to override doWriteResponse() of org.apache.camel.component.http4.DefaultHttpBinding, but no go.  Could you please share a small example that I could refer to?

Comment: You can throw an exception in that method if the status code != 200. Or alternative set an exception on the exchange.setException.